# Array of Pointer. Get value of a Element of the Pointer

Tags: c++

I got an array of pointers of my Class:

```
myclass *v[3];
myclass *p;
v[0] = p;
```

I know that I can get the adress with `val=v[0]`. But how can I get the Value of `v[0]`?

Comment: Well, `*(v[0])`. I think you need a good book on C++, this is not a language you can guess.

Comment: @YSC Parens not always necessary, in this case `*v[0]` will do as well.

Comment: `v[0]` is the value, i guess you want the object that pointer is pointing to, but I have to disappoint you: `v[0]` points at garbage

Comment: @CiaPan They are when you're a beginner, which OP is clearly ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as not useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dereference operator `*` e.g. `*arr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`v[0]` is a pointer. TO access the value of a pointee, you need to dereference it. 
Use the dereference operator, that is `*`.

```
*v[0]
```